# Using Any class (similar to boost::any) in other templates

Tags: c++, c++11

I have implemented a pure C++11 Any class (based on [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20058/c11-any-class)) which is similar to boost::any and works nicely if used directly.

However I need to use this now as template parameter to assign parameters to variables. Look at this:

```
class A {
  IRecognizer<Any, Any> *_recognizer;

  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  A(IRecognizer<T1, T2> *x) : _recognizer(x) {
  }
}
```

and

```
template<typename Symbol, typename ATNInterpreter>
class IRecognizer {
public:

  virtual int getState() = 0;

};
```

Even though I could assign each template parameter to an Any variable, I'm not allowed to assign `IRecognizer<T1, T2> to IRecognizer<Any, Any>`. Is there a solution for this problem? The error message is:

```
Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'IRecognizer<Any, Any> *'
with an lvalue of type 'IRecognizer<Token *, ParserATNSimulator *> *'
```

The reason I use the Any class is to have a common type that could be assigned with any class reference (similar to Java's Object, but C++ has no common object type from which all other classes derive).

Maybe a different approach is possible here? I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure the appropriate constructor exists and is instantiable? Also, show the compiler error please. Also, what's B?

Comment: `IRecognizer<Any, Any> *` and `IRecognizer<Token *, ParserATNSimulator *> *` are pointers to two different types, which do not have a common base class, so you can't assign one pointer to the other.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert a `IRecognizer<T1, T2> *` to a `IRecognizer<Any, Any> *`. The only allowed pointer conversion is from a derived class pointer to a base class pointer (i.e. `Derived*`  to `Base*`) or to a more *cv*-qualified pointer to the same type (i.e. `Derived*` to `Derived const*`) or both.

`IRecognizer<T1,T2>` is not in the same class hierarchy as `IRecognizer<Any, Any>`. They are two unrelated types. You can add a constructor to convert an `IRecognizer<A,B>` to an `IRecognizer<C,D>` if that makes sense, but you can't add a similar thing for pointers.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to X is not the same as an X.

While you can convert an X into a Y (a `IRecognizer<T1,T2>` into an `IRecognizer<Any,Any>`), you cannot convert a pointer to `X` into a pointer to `Y`.

You may not want a pointer here.  Instead, you might want a value.

However, an interface is not a value.

---

Java generics are not like C++ templates.  A Java generic `Bob<Type>` is a wrapper around `Bob<Object>` -- it is actually storing an `Object`, with a bunch of wrapping casts to-and-from in a layer on top of it.

You can write such wrappers in C++.  As an example:

```
class IRecognizer_base {
public:
  virtual int getState() = 0;
};
template<typename Symbol, typename ATNInterpreter>
class IRecognizer:public IRecognizer_base {
};
```

Now, suppose `getState()` returned a `Symbol`:

```
class IRecognizer_base {
public:
  virtual Any getState_() = 0;
};
template<typename Symbol, typename ATNInterpreter>
class IRecognizer:public IRecognizer_base {
public:
  inline Symbol getState() {
    return getState_(); // whatever conversion required to go from `Any` to `Symbol`
  }
};
```

here, we expose the fact that our objects *actually* return an `Any`, but in the interface we cast them over.

---

If you actually exposed what operations are actually different based on the template types, you can do type erasing tactics that let you store anything that can do those operations instead of a pointer to a specific type.